# Bounty label wrapping incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties, ios-app

I just noticed that for questions with open bounties, the blue label is wrapping improperly (iPhone 6 on iOS 8.1 here):

[image: wrapping?]

Comment: That's hilarious.

Comment: This bug has been identified and fixed in a branch – will answer question once it has been fixed on main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had an extra space character before the "+50" part that also had its background set to blue. When it wrapped at the end of the line, it would render as shown above.

This has been fixed; fix is currently available in Beta Version 1.2.1.184.