# Can vote more than once (when a question is migrated)

Tags: discussion, bug, voting, migration

A [Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284554/bounty-label-wrapping-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment147807_284554) was recently migrated to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/bounty-label-wrapping-incorrectly)
because it was about a Network-wide bug with the Stack Exchange iOS application.

Before it was migrated I upvoted the question on Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]

..and the vote was carried across to Meta Stack Exchange, *but* it **doesn't think I've voted yet**:

[image]

..meaning I can upvote the question *again*:

[image]

This bug could exist because the system may only migrate the *number* of votes, not including *who* actually voted.

If so, it can't *really be called 'Migration*, but rather be called *copy and delete*.

Is this bug intentional?